# client always pops up a msgbox before connecting

Tags: emacsclient

My Emacs server uses a **non-localhost** IP address to listen for potential TCP connections.

Each time I run `emacsclientw.exe`, the message box

[image]

will pop up.

Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code at <https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lib-src/emacsclient.c?h=emacs-29#n1057>:

```c
if (server.in.sin_addr.s_addr != inet_addr("127.0.0.1") && !quiet)
    message(false, "%s: connected to remote socket at %s\n",
```

I just need to make the variable `quiet` `true`:

So the answer is to pass a `--quiet` argument to the client:

```shell
emacsclientw.exe --quiet --args...
```

Comment: Of course I know that `emacsclientw -h` can be used to view help information, but the Emacs server I originally used uses the localhost IP address. So despite not passing the `--quiet` to `emacsclientw`, no msgbox pops up. This led to my oversight of this parameter.